# Slide label down

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm building a game where I want a label to slide down. I watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ckl7kSwmlbY) where it works just fine, but it doesn't work on my project, it (firstLabel) just disappears and appears in the expected coordinate.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: [], animations: {

    self.firstLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 1.125, y: self.frame.height / 3)

    }, completion: nil)
```

Ps: firstLabel was declared as `SKLabelNode()`

Comment: An SKLabelNode is not a UIView and would, therefore, not be managed by a UIView animation context.  You are going to have to look into the functionality of SpriteKit to animate that entity.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I'm totally new to coding, so I don't know much of it. How do I look into it? Is there anywhere that talks about SpriteKit animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing your frameworks. You use UIView animation blocks to animate UIViews, not SpriteKit nodes. What you're looking for is [SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html).

```
self.firstLabel.runAction(
    SKAction.moveTo(
        CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 1.125, y: self.frame.height / 3),
        duration: 0.5
    )
)
```

Comment: But if I want to make this "bouncing", setting the delay to 0.2 (just like the video I mentioned above -its is at 6:13-), instead of 0.0 (basic slide). How can I make this work with SKAction (or another way)?

Comment: @Luiz I don't know exactly, but you could split the SKAction out into its own variable and utilize its [timingFunction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKAction/timingFunction) property.  It takes a function that takes and returns a Float and you can use it to specify the timing. I'm not familiar with the math required for this. It's unfortunate, but as far as I know, there isn't an "out of the box" solution for this like there is in UIKit.

Comment: I'm gonna try to do this. Thank you again!! =)